# Force ebean to not include an ID in a generated query

Tags: java, ebean

I'm building a select that has to get me all distinct values from a table.

**The sql I would normally write would look like this:** `"SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST FROM MUSICLIB"`

**However, ebean is generating the following:** `"SELECT DISTINCT ID, ARTIST FROM MUSICLIB"`

**The finder is as such:**

```
find.select("artist").setDistinct(true).findList();
```

I've found that ebean is generating this ID on every single query, no matter what options I set.

How do I accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Update: This issue was fixed in version 4.2.0 as per github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, Ebean for objects mapping requires ID field, and if you won't include it you'll get some mysterious exceptions.

Instead you can query DB without mapping and then write your SQL statement yourself:

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery("SELECT DISTINCT artist FROM musiclib");
List<SqlRow> rows = sqlQuery.findList();

for (SqlRow row : rows) {
    debug("I got one: " + row.getString("artist"));
}
```

Of course if `artist` is a relation, you need to perform additional query using list of found IDs with `in(...)` expression.

Comment: Alright then, but following up on that, what about when ebean generates prefixed table names and we can't look then up in a remote install? I've stumbled upon the answer you gave already but now the table names are a problem as they might be generated differently on a different DB, depending on what the customer wants. I've found some stuff about NamingConvention from the Ebean ServerConfig, but that returns null. Should I make a separate question for that?

Comment: How do you set the table prefixes?

Comment: Meanwhile, I've created this bug report: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/158

Comment: About the prefixes: that I do not know. I assume it's something ebean is capable of and that some customers might want for all their tables.

Comment: TBH I always require from my clients EMPTY databases, so no need for additional prefixing, in such case tablename will not change ever :) you can i.e. add a config property in your application.conf for table prefix, so you will be able to read it and use prefixed tablename in custom queries.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Got confirmation in that ticket that ebean will always generate the same table name regardless of DB and the ticket has been accepted.